# How do I match records to a specific month of current year and output under months?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to match all the rows in a table to a specific month. I want my output to look like this:

```
return [

'January' => [
     'total_sales' => 100
],
'February' => [
     'total_sales' => 50
],
'Match' => [
    'total_sales' => 2
 ],
];
```

So the month period starts at the beginning of the year (January) and ends until today's date (April) if we are in June then I should see total sales from June, if we are in July same thing etc..

This is what I have so far to loop from the beginning of the year until today's month.

```
for($i=date('n');$i>0;$i--)
{
    var_dump(date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, ($i), 2, date('Y'))));

}
```

This is what I have to pull query from mySQL:

```
  `SELECT * FROM total_sales WHERE  created_at > (NOW() - INTERVAL {starts from January till today's month} MONTH)`
```

My Problem:
How do can I display the output I can to accomplish above?

Comment: where's the php code that executes the query? You can get SQL to return just the `Month(created_at)` and `total_sales`? Including `CREATE TABLE total_sales` might be useful

Comment: can you provide an example? I'm using laravel as the backend.

Comment: Someone popped something in the answers area  below.

Comment: You should have tagged as "laravel". I added the tag.

Comment: not necessarily, this is not about laravel is about php and mysql. laravel = php

Comment: Ok then. I removed the tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can group on month,

```
select date_format(created_at,"%b"),sum(sale_amount) from total_sales where created_at > '2020-01-01 00:00:00' group by date_format(created_at,"%b");
```

Comment: would be `sum(sale_amount)` rather than count making some assumption about table format.